# How do I get filter to work with my subquery?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, pivot-table

The code provided works fine and outputs as shown in the table below it

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT   setsTbl.s_id, setsTbl.setName, trainingTbl.t_date, userProfilesTbl.No + ' ' + userProfilesTbl.surname AS Name, userProfilesTbl.st_id, userProfilesTbl.wa_id, userAssessmentTbl.o_id, row_number() over
(
partition by setsTbl.s_id

                order by trainingTbl.t_date ASC
            ) r
FROM         userProfilesTbl RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      userAssessmentTbl ON userProfilesTbl.UserId = userAssessmentTbl.UserId RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      trainingTbl ON userAssessmentTbl.tt_id = trainingTbl.tt_id RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      setsTbl ON trainingTbl.s_id = setsTbl.s_id 

                      )x
WHERE x.r =1


s_id   setName  Name       o_id      
-----  -----   -----      ------
1       100     Barnes      2
2       100     Beardsley   3
3       101     Aldridge    1
4       102     Molby       2
5       102     Whelan      3
```

im using a datatable in ASP.NET coupled with a DropDownlist which controls the date and 2 fields userProfilestbl.st and userProfilesTbl.wa which allows me to filter the shop and shift the person/user is working.

How do i add my filters to the present subquery.

This is the filter/parameter I'm using

```
   (userProfilesTbl.st_id=2 AND userProfilesTbl.wa_id=2) AND (DATEPART(yyyy,t_date) = 2013 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert this clause in the sub query after the from clause. Please look at the following query for some idea:

```
    SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT   setsTbl.s_id, setsTbl.setName, trainingTbl.t_date, userProfilesTbl.No + ' ' + userProfilesTbl.surname AS Name, userProfilesTbl.st_id, userProfilesTbl.wa_id, userAssessmentTbl.o_id, row_number() over
(
partition by setsTbl.s_id

                order by trainingTbl.t_date ASC
            ) r
FROM         userProfilesTbl RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      userAssessmentTbl ON userProfilesTbl.UserId = userAssessmentTbl.UserId RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      trainingTbl ON userAssessmentTbl.tt_id = trainingTbl.tt_id RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      setsTbl ON trainingTbl.s_id = setsTbl.s_id 

WHERE (userProfilesTbl.st_id=2 AND userProfilesTbl.wa_id=2) AND (DATEPART(yyyy,t_date) = 2013 ))x
WHERE x.r =1
```